# Create a marker icon with svg

Tags: css, leaflet

It's more of a CSS question. But I have added leaflet as a tag, because probably some leaflet experts can answer this too.

I want to set a custom marker for a leaflet card. **This should look something like this one (with round border around the svg):**

[image]

*The original image is here: https://www.geoapify.com/static/b4294748392f1bc2dab8ae94cfa99a3f/3825b/map-marker-icon.webp*

And I want to put a SVG in the pointer. **Question** How can i do that?

I got as far as here.

```css
.marker-pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
  padding:8px;  
}
// to draw white circle
.marker-pin::after {
    content: '';
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class='marker-pin'>
  <svg style="background-color:white;" class="material-icons custom-div-icon" enable-background="new 0 0 396.079 396.079" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 396.08 396.08" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    
        <path d="m368.74 147.22c7.356-18.313 7.362-36.373-1.709-48.867-16.381-22.556-56.126-18.441-88.78 9.187-32.935 27.868-37.662 71.655-34.661 80.346 2.68 8.795 32.242 41.438 75.267 44.629 42.656 3.157 77.229-16.876 77.225-44.753-5e-3 -15.444-10.625-30.052-27.342-40.542z"/>
        <path d="m313.31 249.57c-36.682-22.711-79.787-13.676-87.125-8.136-7.535 5.267-29.447 43.469-19.186 85.374 10.18 41.545 39.915 68.232 66.426 59.614 14.685-4.776 25.294-19.39 30.106-38.53 19.69 1.339 36.869-4.237 45.949-16.726 16.39-22.549 0.198-59.078-36.17-81.596z"/>
        <path d="m169.89 241.43c-7.338-5.54-50.442-14.573-87.124 8.136-36.366 22.519-52.56 59.047-36.171 81.598 9.08 12.488 26.258 18.063 45.948 16.726 4.813 19.142 15.424 33.756 30.107 38.53 26.511 8.618 56.248-18.069 66.425-59.614 10.264-41.908-11.65-80.111-19.185-85.376z"/>
        <path d="m77.225 232.52c43.024-3.188 72.586-35.834 75.267-44.628 3-8.692-1.728-52.477-34.662-80.347-32.653-27.628-72.398-31.741-88.78-9.187-9.073 12.495-9.066 30.555-1.708 48.868-16.717 10.491-27.337 25.099-27.342 40.54-3e-3 27.878 34.568 47.911 77.225 44.754z"/>
        <path d="m198.04 154.79c9.192 0.168 49.374-17.856 65.703-57.792 16.185-39.593 7.813-78.664-18.699-87.273-14.687-4.769-31.86 0.818-47.004 13.477-15.144-12.657-32.318-18.244-47.004-13.477-26.513 8.609-34.884 47.682-18.698 87.273 16.326 39.935 56.51 57.96 65.702 57.792z"/>
        <circle cx="198.04" cy="198.04" r="35"/></svg>  
</div>
```

*I got the original CSS from here.
https://www.geoapify.com/create-custom-map-marker-icon Under the item "Create a marker icon with Material Design icon".*